# Why does a preassigned function pointer perform worse than a branch?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, function-pointers

I have a class with an `enum` member variable. One of the member functions bases its behavior on this `enum` so as a "possible" optimization, I have the two different behaviors as two different functions and I give the class a member function pointer which is set at construction. I simulated this situation like this:

```
enum catMode {MODE_A, MODE_B};

struct cat
{
    cat(catMode mode) : stamp_(0), mode_(mode) {}

    void
    update()
    {
        stamp_ = (mode_ == MODE_A) ? funcA() : funcB();
    }

    uint64_t stamp_;
    catMode  mode_;
};

struct cat2
{
    cat2(catMode mode) : stamp_(0), mode_(mode)
    {
        if (mode_ = MODE_A)
            func_ = funcA;
        else
            func_ = funcB;
    }

    void
    update()
    {
        stamp_ = func_();
    }

    uint64_t stamp_;
    catMode  mode_;
    uint64_t (*func_)(void);
};
```

And then I create a cat object and an array of length `32`. I traverse the array to bring it into cache, then I call cats update method `32` times and store the latency using `rdtsc` in the array...

Then I call a function which loops several hundred times using `rand()`, `ulseep()`, and some arbitrary `strcmp()`..come back and I do the `32` thing again.

The result is that the method with the branch seems to always be around `44` +/- `10` cycles whereas the one with the function pointer tends to be around `130`. I'm curious as to why this would be the case?

If anything, I would have expected similar performance. Also, templating is hardly an option because full specialization of the real cat class for that one function would be overkill.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - possible more that the CPU has branch prediction while a function pointer call involves clearing stack/register. You wouldn't necessarily see this from the assem

Comment: depending on `funcA` and `funcB`s complexities, they could have been inlined. I agree with @sixlettervariables that checking the assembly is a good idea. It's easy to do, and if nothing else, at least you'll rule out some possible explanations.

Comment: You can avoid full specialization when you use a templated struct to wrap the specific function. Then you only need to specialize the struct and the cat class needs to be specified only once.

Comment: What processor is this? Also, can you provide a complete SSCCE so I can run this myself?

Comment: @tokage wait that is interesting, where can I read about this or how does this work?

Comment: @Palace Chan [example at ideone](http://ideone.com/GnWRX), of course you can use this only if you can template the Cat class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a complete SSCCE I can't approach this the same way that I usually do with such questions.
So the best I can do is speculate:

The core difference between your two cases is that you have a branch vs. a function pointer. The fact that you are seeing a difference at all strongly hints that `funcA()` and `funcB()` are very small functions.

**Possibility #1:**

In the branch version of the code, `funcA()` and `funcB()` are being inlined by the compiler. Not only does that skip the function call overhead, but if the functions are trivial enough, the branch could also be completely optimized out as well.

Function pointers, on the other hand, cannot be inlined unless the compiler can resolve them at compile-time.

**Possibility #2:**

By comparing a branch against a function-pointer, you are putting the [branch-predictor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) against the [branch target predictor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_target_predictor).

Branch target prediction is not the same as branch prediction. In the branch case, the processor needs to predict which way to branch. In the function pointer case, it needs to predict where to branch to.

It's very likely that your processor's branch predictor is much more accurate than its branch target predictor. But then again, this is all guesswork...

Comment: Thanks! I wish I had seen this before. What is a complete SSCCE? Yea funcA and funcB are relatively small. It is a 2 cpu intel Xeon with 6 cores per cpu.

Comment: SSCCE = Short Self Contained Compilable Example, so basically a small snippet that reproduces the problem that you're having.

Comment: what is a good way/resource to learn the strong points, latencies, and such of your processor? For example Xeon, or Sandy Bridge? I think it would help make better (albeit nonportable) optimization decisions.

Comment: [Agner Fog's blog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) has some very good resources. He's got large table of latencies of the majority of current x86 processors. But be aware that performance is a lot more complicated than just adding up latencies. So you'll have to do a lot of testing and experimentation.